Проблема с beaver builder кастомный модуль
Я использую плагин beaver builder и хочу сделать свой модуль. Но я делаю что-то не так, потому что даже если модуль не установлен, сайт все равно пишет эту ошибку.

Notice: Undefined index: module_advanced in**/var/www/html/academy24_chili/v_stepanov/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/classes/class-fl-builder-model.phpon line2883**

Вот структура в папках и файлах:
/beaver_builder/
    /inc/ 
        /HT-beaver-modules/
            /reviews-slider/
                reviews-slider-module.php
                style.css 
                script.js 
                includes/
                    frontend.php
  page_beaver-builder.php 
  function.php

function.php:
if ( ! defined( 'MY_MODULES_DIR' ) ) {
    define( 'MY_MODULES_DIR', get_template_directory() . '/inc/HT-beaver-modules/' );
}

if ( ! defined( 'MY_MODULES_URL' ) ) {
    define( 'MY_MODULES_URL', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/HT-beaver-modules/' );
}

function my_load_module_examples() {
    if ( class_exists( 'FLBuilder' ) ) {
        require_once MY_MODULES_DIR . 'reviews-slider/reviews-slider-module.php';
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_load_module_examples' );

reviews-slider-module.php:
  class ReviewsSliderModule extends FLBuilderModule {
                    public function __construct() {
                        parent::__construct(array(
                            'name'            => __('Reviews Slider', 'fl-builder'),
                            'description'     => __('Slider for displaying reviews', 'fl-builder'),
                            'group'           => __('Custom Modules', 'fl-builder'),
                            'category'        => __('Content Modules', 'fl-builder'),
                            'dir'             => MY_MODULES_DIR . 'reviews-slider/',
                            'url'             => MY_MODULES_URL . 'reviews-slider/',
                            'editor_export'   => true,
                            'enabled'         => true,
                            'partial_refresh' => true,
                            'class'           => 'fl-module-reviews-slider-module',
                            'id'              => 'reviews-slider-module',
                            'animation'       => '',
                            'module_advanced' => isset($settings->module_advanced) ? $settings->module_advanced : array(),
                        ));
                    }`
                    public function enqueue_scripts() {
                        wp_enqueue_style('reviews-slider-style', $this->url . 'style.css');
                        wp_enqueue_script('slick-slider', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
                        wp_enqueue_script('reviews-slider-script', $this->url . 'script.js', array('jquery', 'slick-slider'), '', true);
                    }
                    
                    public function render($settings) {
                        include($this->dir . 'includes/frontend.php');
                    }
                    
                    private function get_review_categories() {
                        $categories = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'category'));
                        $options = array();
                        foreach ($categories as $category) {
                            $options[$category->slug] = $category->name;
                        }
                        return $options;
                    }
      FLBuilder::register_module('ReviewsSliderModule', array(
                        'my_loop_settings' => array(
                            'title' => __('Loop Settings', 'fl-builder'),
                             'file'  => FL_BUILDER_DIR . 'includes/ui-loop-settings.php',
                        ),
                    ))`;

frontend.php:
   $query = FLBuilderLoop::query($settings);
                
                if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
                    <div class="reviews-slider">
                        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="review-item">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <div class="review-content">
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                else:
                    echo '<p>' . __('No reviews found.', 'fl-builder') . '</p>';
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                } else {echo __('No settings provided.', 'fl-builder');}`

